# Where can I customize the content tree gutter flyout/context menu?

Tags: content-editor

When you right-click in the left gutter of the Content Tree in the Content Editor, a really handy context menu appears with some "command shortcuts" (for lack of a better term).

[image]

Does anyone know where in the core database the "buttons" for this context menu are controlled? *Bonus points to anyone who can also tell me the real name for this thing, because I can't seem to find it anywhere.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add stuff here: `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Context Menues/Default` and seeing the path I would assume it is called a "Context Menu".

After your command and screenshot: you'll need to go here in the core database:

```
/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Gutters
```

Apparently they are just called "Gutters". All existing ones have that name also in their namespace.

Comment: That's not it - the buttons in there are totally different. I just uploaded a screenshot to help point to the "context menu" thingy that I am referring to

Comment: Updated with new path..  (left the old one to keep your comment useful)

Comment: Wow...I have no clue how I missed that...

Answer (score 2):

**Sitecore PowerShell Extensions** provides the ability to add commands to the "Gutter". Here is an excerpt from the [book](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/content-editor.html).

The Gutter integration allows for full flexibility of adding a gutter element.

1. Begin by adding a new script to the Gutters library.
2. Edit the script to create a new instance of `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Gutters.GutterIconDescriptor` if the right conditions are met.

   - Set the Icon, Tooltip, and Click properties.
   - Return the gutter object
3. Rebuild the gutter integration from within the ISE.

   - Settings tab
   - Integration chunk
   - Sync Library with Content Editor Gutter command

**Note:** Examples included in the following modules

- Publishing Status Gutter

[image: Publishing Status]

Comment: Of course, it does! :) I should have known!